# Wie formuliert man die Besessenheit von einem Geist aktiv?

Tags: verb

Folgendes sollte ein gramatikalisch korrekter Satz sein:

> Ich bin von Antons Geist besessen.

Wie kann man das aktiv ausdrücken? Also etwas wie

> Antons Geist _____ mich.

besetzt? besitzt? besesst?

Mir fällt es nur indirekt ein:

> Antons Geist hat mich in Besetz genommen.

Kann man das noch anders sagen?

Comment: Ich denke das erste Beispiel ist das gebräuchlichste, _in Besitz genommen_ würde aber auch gehen.

Comment: Schon klar. Zum Kontext: Meine Freundin hat einen Geist gespielt und hat "Ich besesse dich!" gesagt. Das klingt falsch. Das nächstbeste das mir Einfällt ist "Ich nehme dich in Besitz!"

Comment: _"Ich besesse Dich!"_ ist definitiv falsch. In einem satirischen Kontext würde ich vielleicht _"Ich besetze Dich"_ sagen, das ist dann gewissermassen doppeldeutig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mit deinem Satz »Ich bin von Antons Geist besessen« meinst du offenbar nicht »Ich bin von Antons intellektuellen Leistungen hochgradig begeistert«, wie ich zuerst dachte. Du meinst vielmehr, dass ein Geist die Kontrolle über einen Menschen übernommen hat. Das könnte man folgendermaßen ausdrücken:

> Antons Geist beherrscht mich!

> Antons Geist hat mich in seiner Gewalt!

bzw. wenn der Geist spricht:

> Ich beherrsche dich!

> Ich habe dich in meiner Gewalt!

Comment: wenn der Geist "die Kontrolle über einen Menschen übernommen hat", wie du schreibst, warum dann nicht "konntolliert" :)

Answer (score 4):

Etwas altmodischer:

> Antons Geist ist in mich gefahren!

Answer (score 4):

Häufig verwendet man eine Formulierung mit "Besitz ergreifen", in der Regel allerdings in der Vergangenheit:

> Antons Geist hat von mir Besitz ergriffen.